# What is the best way to send video between two iOS devices?

Tags: ios

I would like people to be able to send short videos to each other in my app... What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bit explaining the context might help you to have a better answer. But in broad, icloud should be a useful technology to resolve your problem.

[iCloud for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php)

Comment: isn't iCloud for pushing data to your own devices? I want to let users send data to eachother.